# Need help separating words that end or begin with extendended latin characters (regex and php)

Tags: php, regex

I have a text file.
The PHP script looks for each one of the words in it and returns all sentences containing them.

This works fine on letters of the english alphabet, and if the extended latin characters (čćžšđ) are contained within the word.

The problem arises when the characters (čćžšđ) are at the end or beginning of the word,
the script doesn't return any results.

What could be the problem?

My code is below:

```
<?php

$book = file_get_contents('book.txt');

$word = preg_split('/\s+/', $book);

$sentence = preg_split('/(?<=[.?!])\s+(?=[a-z])/i', $book);

foreach ($word as $value) {
    
    // removes special characters
    $value = str_replace(array(':', '\\', '/', '*', ',', '.', '!', '?', '(', ')', '-', '_', '"', '„', '"'), "", $value);
    
    // gives a title
    echo "<h2>" . $value . " </h2>";
    
    foreach ($sentence as $value2) {    

        if(preg_match("/\b{$value}\b/", $value2)){      
            // writes down all sentences containing the title
            echo $value2 . " <br />";
        }
        
    }
    
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, I replaced

```
if(preg_match("/\b{$value}\b/", $value2)){
```

with

```
if(preg_match("/\s{$value}\s|\s{$value}(?:,)|\s{$value}\\!|\s{$value}\\./", $value2)){
```

Comment: Any time the target string contains characters > U+100 it is considered Unicode. Php regex only works properly if you tell it the target is Unicode. That is done by adding the modifier `//u` at the end of the regex i.e `/\b{$value}\b/u`. It is seen here that word boundary's work correctly then https://regex101.com/r/qBjk3T/1/. However I don't believe that is the only problem. It could be that the split should include those special Unicode char's as well. Just an example split regex `(?<=[.?!])\s+(?=[a-zā-ſ])`